# I need to fetch data from mysql database by week number how can i?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to fetch data from `mysql` database weeknumber in where clause 
like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE addedon(WEEK(2))
```

I have week numbers of year and I need to fetch data by that week number.

Comment: Something like this `... WHERE WEEK([column]) = 2`

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE WEEK(addedon) = ?` where `?` is number of week which you want filter by

Also `WEEK()` receives second parameter `mode` and can return different values. [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)